# Could anybody add a new tag for design system react?

Tags: support, tags

The design-system-react repo [suggests](https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react/blob/master/docs/SUPPORT.md) posting support questions with the tag `design-system-react`.

I can't find this tag.  Could someone with sufficient reputation please add this tag?

Comment: This is Salesforce stack exchange. The note on the repo suggest to post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-system-react) where the tag already exist.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake.  As an aside I don't see the tag on stack overflow either but I'll obviously be able to follow that up over there.

Answer (score -1):

This site is not Stack Overflow. It is an exchange specific to Salesforce implementations. If you have questions about React in implementations you are not building on Salesforce, they would be off topic here.

Comment: I have a question that, I think, concerns both design system react and the salesforce platform.